# Rasterio show_hist display issue

Tags: python, rasterio, sentinel-2, plot, histogram

I'm trying to display the histogram for the bands but I keep getting the following object whenever I execute `show_hist`.

[image]

Here is the code I executed:

```
from rasterio.plot import show_hist
show_hist(full_dataset, bins=50, lw=0.0, stacked=False, alpha=0.3,
              histtype='stepfilled', title="Histogram")
```

How do I remove  from the plot? Moreover, the legend is not shown. Could this be related to the very large values?

Answer (score 1):

You have to encapsulate your code in a matplotlib figure.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show_hist

src = rasterio.open("file.tif")
fig, axhist = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(20, 20))
show_hist(src, ax=axhist, bins=100, lw=0.0, stacked=False, alpha=0.3, histtype='stepfilled', density=True, title="Title")
axhist.get_legend().remove()
plt.show()
```